# Create a new view with different scopes in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user

  scope :my_revisions, ->(user){ where("posts.user_id = ?", user.id)}
  scope :visible_posts, -> {where(visible: true)}
  scope :pending_posts, -> {where(visible: false)}
end
```

when i go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts` i see all my posts. What i wanna do now, is create a new view "revision.html.erb" that will show me just the posts where the boolean field "visible" is set to false, when i go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/revisions`

I created the view "revision.html.erb" within the posts folder in my views, and put in the routes.rb:

```
  get 'posts/revisions'
```

I'm getting "Couldn't find Post with 'id'=revisions"
It looks like it's trying to enter into the before filter that is in the controller

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

but as you can see, it's set to only show, edit, update, and destroy...

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that Rails thinks "revisions" is an id, and tries to look up one for you which obviously doesn't work.

You can do this

```
# routes.rb
resources :posts do
  get 'revisions', on: :collection
end

# posts_controller
def revisions
  @posts = Post.where(...)
end
```

Can read more about this in [the Rails guides about routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)